# ggplot bar chart: Scale_gradient_color: Need to set limits and breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

```
values= c('Customers', 'Preparedness', 'Integrity', 'ContImprov', 'Teamwork', 'Employees', 'Community', 'Communications')
mean = c(2.714,2.800, 2.809, 2.084, 2.02, 2.39, 2.56, 2.48)
count = c(49, 20, 42, 59, 55, 63, 37, 47) 
data = data.frame(Values = values, Mean = mean, Count = count)
```

I want to create a bar chart for this data, BUT I need the color ramp in the legend and the colors in general to be from a scale of 1 to 4. It just happens that my mean values are ~ 2. Below is the code I have tried:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Value, y = Count, fill = Mean))
    + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
    + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
    + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Average Rank"))
    + ylab("Responses")
    + guides(limits = c(1,4),fill = guide_colorbar(reverse = TRUE))
    + scale_colour_gradient( guide = "colourbar", limits = c(1,4), breaks=c(1,2,3,4))
```

I assumed the limits and breaks argument would accomplish what I want, but it doesn't seem to affect my output.  Below is an image of what I get instead.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Henrik's suggestion was correct, I should have used scale_fill_gradient.

[Here is the correct graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLJRq.png)

Comment: `fill != color`; try a `scale_fill_xxx` instead.

Comment: Henrik, something like scale_fill_manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Henrik mentioned `fill != color`. So changing `scale_colour_gradient` to `scale_fill_gradient` gets you:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Values, y = count, fill = Mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Average Rank")) +
  ylab("Responses") +
  guides(limits = c(1,4),fill = guide_colorbar(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(1,4), breaks=c(1,2,3,4))
```

Which I believe is what you were looking for. You can also change the colors used via the `low =` and `high =` arguments.